# Fluid CSS Product Grid with Full width Drop Down Panel (Without Absolute Positioning)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have been presented with what seems to be quite a challenging design, I can't seem to find a solution in my own head so I am reaching out to the community to see if anyone has come across a similar problem.

I have an eCommerce store that has a category landing page, the markup is similar to the markup above, although the markup above has been simplified for the purpose of the question. The content is generated by PHP so it needs to be setup this way as its in a foreach loop.

The idea is that you have this responsive grid ranging from 1 item to 20items(if necessary) it is displaying information about the category that is corresponds to, it is a minified version. When you click on the 'View More' button/link then a further panel drops down thus displaying more detailed information. My problem is that because the items are a fixed width, and they are all floating left so as they are displayed in a grid, my subcategory drop is then bound by the parent container, is there any way of getting this drop down panel to display full width outside of its parent container? below the grid items(See Diagram), and also not be absolutely positioned as I would like the grid items below the drop down panel to be pushed down with some jQuery.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <style type="text/css">
  .subcategory-grid {
   padding: 0 0 120px;
   max-width: 1280px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto
  }

  .subcategory-grid::after {
   clear: both;
   content: "";
   display: table
  }

  .subcategory-grid::after {
   clear: both;
   content: "";
   display: table
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-item {
   cursor: pointer;
   margin-top: 28px;
   margin-bottom: 28px
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-item img {
   max-width: 100%;
   min-width: 100%
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
   .subcategory-grid .subcategory-item-container {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 1.75788%;
    width: 49.12106%;
    margin-top: 28px;
    margin-bottom: 28px;
    float: left !important
   }

   .subcategory-grid .subcategory-item-container:last-child {
    margin-right: 0
   }

   .subcategory-grid .subcategory-item-container:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 0
   }

   .subcategory-grid .subcategory-item-container:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: left
   }
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-item-container:hover .view-more {
   border-bottom: 6px solid #000
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-info {
   text-align: center
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-info h2 {
   margin-top: 25px
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-info h2 a {
   font-size: 24px
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-info .category-description {
   margin: 20px 0
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-info .view-more {
   text-align: center !important;
   background: url('../img/icon/arrow-right-black.png?1437173465') no-repeat right 1px;
   padding-right: 15px;
   padding-bottom: 10px
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-info .view-more:hover {
   border-bottom: 6px solid #000
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-drop {
   display: none;
   border-top: 1px solid #cecece;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #cecece;
   padding-bottom: 35px
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-drop .title {
   position: relative;
   display: block
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-drop .title h2 {
   font-size: 1.875rem;
   text-align: center;
   border-bottom: 6px solid #000;
   margin: 35px auto;
   max-width: 426px;
   padding-bottom: 5px
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-drop .title .close-button {
   position: absolute;
   height: 30px;
   width: 30px;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-indent: 100%;
   white-space: nowrap;
   display: block;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   background: url('../img/icon/cart-icon-remove.png?1437234524') no-repeat 0 0
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-drop .top strong {
   text-transform: uppercase
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-drop .top p, .subcategory-grid .subcategory-drop .top .block-video-hub .videohub-item .videohub_item_subtitle, .block-video-hub .videohub-item .subcategory-grid .subcategory-drop .top .videohub_item_subtitle {
   margin-bottom: 22px
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-drop .middle {
   padding: 15px 0
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-drop .middle ul li {
   padding: 7px 0
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="subcategory-grid">
  <div class="subcategory-item-container">
   <div class="subcategory-item">
    <!--Item Content-->
    <img src="http://placehold.it/620x350"/>
    <a href="#" class="view-more">View More</a>
    <div class="subcategory-drop is-hidden">
     <!--Drop Down Content-->
     <p>Hello from the dropdown</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subcategory-item-container">
   <div class="subcategory-item">
    <!--Item Content-->
    <img src="http://placehold.it/620x350"/>
    <a href="#" class="view-more">View More</a>
    <div class="subcategory-drop is-hidden">
     <!--Drop Down Content-->
     <p>Hello from the dropdown</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subcategory-item-container">
   <div class="subcategory-item">
    <!--Item Content-->
    <img src="http://placehold.it/620x350"/>
    <a href="#" class="view-more">View More</a>
    <div class="subcategory-drop is-hidden">
     <!--Drop Down Content-->
     <p>Hello from the dropdown</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subcategory-item-container">
   <div class="subcategory-item">
    <!--Item Content-->
    <img src="http://placehold.it/620x350"/>
    <a href="#" class="view-more">View More</a>
    <div class="subcategory-drop is-hidden">
     <!--Drop Down Content-->
     <p>Hello from the dropdown</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subcategory-item-container">

   <div class="subcategory-item">
    <!--Item Content-->
    <img src="http://placehold.it/620x350"/>
    <a href="#" class="view-more">View More</a>
    <div class="subcategory-drop is-hidden">
     <!--Drop Down Content-->
     <p>Hello from the dropdown</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subcategory-item-container">
   <div class="subcategory-item">
    <!--Item Content-->
    <img src="http://placehold.it/620x350"/>
    <a href="#" class="view-more">View More</a>
    <div class="subcategory-drop is-hidden">
     <!--Drop Down Content-->
     <p>Hello from the dropdown</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 var container = $('.subcategory-grid'),
 rangePanel = container.find('.subcategory-item');

 rangePanel.each(function () {
  var _this = $(this);
  var viewMore = _this.find('.view-more');

  viewMore.on('click', function () {
   var dropPanel = $(this).closest('.subcategory-item-container').find('.subcategory-drop');
   var closeButton = dropPanel.find('.close-button');

   dropPanel.fadeIn();

   closeButton.on('click', function () {
    dropPanel.fadeOut();
   });
  });
 });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Please see this diagram for more information:

[image: diagram]

Comment: I am working on a fiddle; could you include the CSS and JS code? On a side note, are you able to use a framework like Foundation 5 or Bootstrap 3? It can be done without them but they make setting up a grid layout easier.

Comment: Would you mind adding a [runnable code snippet](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) including the compiled CSS?

Comment: @BillyNate I have added a code snippet to the post, any help would be greatly appreciated, as you can see from the code snippet the dropdown is bound to the "parent" would love it to be full width across the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following CSS in your media query but you will need to update your javascript to make sure only one dropdown is visible at a time. Otherwise they will over lap. I put `$('.subcategory-drop').fadeOut(); // Just for demonstration` in the viewMore click function.

```
.subcategory-grid .subcategory-drop {
    left: -103.516%;
    position: relative;
    width: 203.516%;
}

.subcategory-grid .subcategory-item-container:nth-child(2n+1) .subcategory-drop {
    left: 0;  /* reset left on odd items */
}

/**** OR This - A little better optimized than the above ****/

.subcategory-grid .subcategory-drop {
    position: relative;
    width: 203.516%;
}

.subcategory-grid .subcategory-item-container:nth-child(2n) .subcategory-drop {
    left: -103.516%; /* set left on even items */
}
```

**SNIPPET**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <style type="text/css">
  .subcategory-grid {
   padding: 0 0 120px;
   max-width: 1280px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto
  }

  .subcategory-grid::after {
   clear: both;
   content: "";
   display: table
  }

  .subcategory-grid::after {
   clear: both;
   content: "";
   display: table
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-item {
   cursor: pointer;
   margin-top: 28px;
   margin-bottom: 28px
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-item img {
   max-width: 100%;
   min-width: 100%
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
   .subcategory-grid .subcategory-item-container {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 1.75788%;
    width: 49.12106%;
    margin-top: 28px;
    margin-bottom: 28px;
    float: left !important
   }

   .subcategory-grid .subcategory-item-container:last-child {
    margin-right: 0
   }

   .subcategory-grid .subcategory-item-container:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 0
   }

   .subcategory-grid .subcategory-item-container:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: left
   }
        .subcategory-grid .subcategory-drop {
   left: -103.516%;
   position: relative;
   width: 203.516%;
     }

   .subcategory-grid .subcategory-item-container:nth-child(2n+1) .subcategory-drop {
       left: 0;
   }
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-item-container:hover .view-more {
   border-bottom: 6px solid #000
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-info {
   text-align: center
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-info h2 {
   margin-top: 25px
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-info h2 a {
   font-size: 24px
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-info .category-description {
   margin: 20px 0
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-info .view-more {
   text-align: center !important;
   background: url('../img/icon/arrow-right-black.png?1437173465') no-repeat right 1px;
   padding-right: 15px;
   padding-bottom: 10px
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-info .view-more:hover {
   border-bottom: 6px solid #000
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-drop {
   display: none;
   border-top: 1px solid #cecece;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #cecece;
   padding-bottom: 35px
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-drop .title {
   position: relative;
   display: block
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-drop .title h2 {
   font-size: 1.875rem;
   text-align: center;
   border-bottom: 6px solid #000;
   margin: 35px auto;
   max-width: 426px;
   padding-bottom: 5px
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-drop .title .close-button {
   position: absolute;
   height: 30px;
   width: 30px;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-indent: 100%;
   white-space: nowrap;
   display: block;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   background: url('../img/icon/cart-icon-remove.png?1437234524') no-repeat 0 0
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-drop .top strong {
   text-transform: uppercase
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-drop .top p, .subcategory-grid .subcategory-drop .top .block-video-hub .videohub-item .videohub_item_subtitle, .block-video-hub .videohub-item .subcategory-grid .subcategory-drop .top .videohub_item_subtitle {
   margin-bottom: 22px
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-drop .middle {
   padding: 15px 0
  }

  .subcategory-grid .subcategory-drop .middle ul li {
   padding: 7px 0
  }
        
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="subcategory-grid">
  <div class="subcategory-item-container">
   <div class="subcategory-item">
    <!--Item Content-->
    <img src="http://placehold.it/620x350"/>
    <a href="#" class="view-more">View More</a>
    <div class="subcategory-drop is-hidden">
     <!--Drop Down Content-->
     <p>Hello from the dropdown</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subcategory-item-container">
   <div class="subcategory-item">
    <!--Item Content-->
    <img src="http://placehold.it/620x350"/>
    <a href="#" class="view-more">View More</a>
    <div class="subcategory-drop is-hidden">
     <!--Drop Down Content-->
     <p>Hello from the dropdown</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subcategory-item-container">
   <div class="subcategory-item">
    <!--Item Content-->
    <img src="http://placehold.it/620x350"/>
    <a href="#" class="view-more">View More</a>
    <div class="subcategory-drop is-hidden">
     <!--Drop Down Content-->
     <p>Hello from the dropdown</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subcategory-item-container">
   <div class="subcategory-item">
    <!--Item Content-->
    <img src="http://placehold.it/620x350"/>
    <a href="#" class="view-more">View More</a>
    <div class="subcategory-drop is-hidden">
     <!--Drop Down Content-->
     <p>Hello from the dropdown</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subcategory-item-container">

   <div class="subcategory-item">
    <!--Item Content-->
    <img src="http://placehold.it/620x350"/>
    <a href="#" class="view-more">View More</a>
    <div class="subcategory-drop is-hidden">
     <!--Drop Down Content-->
     <p>Hello from the dropdown</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subcategory-item-container">
   <div class="subcategory-item">
    <!--Item Content-->
    <img src="http://placehold.it/620x350"/>
    <a href="#" class="view-more">View More</a>
    <div class="subcategory-drop is-hidden">
     <!--Drop Down Content-->
     <p>Hello from the dropdown</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 var container = $('.subcategory-grid'),
 rangePanel = container.find('.subcategory-item');

 rangePanel.each(function () {
  var _this = $(this);
  var viewMore = _this.find('.view-more');

  viewMore.on('click', function () {

           // Just for demonstration
           $('.subcategory-drop').fadeOut();

   var dropPanel = $(this).closest('.subcategory-item-container').find('.subcategory-drop');
   var closeButton = dropPanel.find('.close-button');

   dropPanel.fadeIn();

   closeButton.on('click', function () {
    dropPanel.fadeOut();
   });
  });
 });
});
</script>
</html>
```